# Pass down the argument value to an annotation

Tags: java, annotations, micronaut

I am trying to create an annotation by combining annother's functionality. Let's say as below:

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
@Around
@io.micronaut.tracing.annotation.NewSpan
public @interface NewSpan {
  String value() default "";
}
```

Now it's seems impossible to pass the `value` to `io.micronaut.tracing.annotation.NewSpan`, after searching many other answers and java docs, it seems impossible to me, any help.

So when I use my `@NewSpan("val")`, it should be passed down to `io.micronaut.tracing.annotation.NewSpan`'s `value`.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you are using Spring (if not it won't work) you can use `@AliasFor`. If not this isn't possible unless you write the synthesized annotations stuff in Spring again for use outside of Spring.

Comment: Not using Spring. I see, let me what can be done, this is good place to start looking at..

Comment: Funfact: micronaut has it too :) Thank you @M.Deinum

Comment: You might want to include that in your question or at least the tags.

Comment: Sure, good idea. At first it seemed to me that this question is purely related to Java.

Comment: "At first it seemed to me that this question is purely related to Java" - It is really related to Micronaut capabilities.  Those could be applied if you were using Java, Groovy, or Kotlin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that should be [the same as in spring](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/context/annotation/AliasFor.html)

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
@Around
@io.micronaut.tracing.annotation.NewSpan
public @interface NewSpan {
  @AliasFor(annotation = io.micronaut.tracing.annotation.NewSpan.class, member="value")
  String value() default "";
}
```